# How to match URL using XPath regular expressions

Tags: regex, xpath

Need help with XPath. I have such a XML:

```
   <unaryExpression tokenValue="'http://google.com'" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="8">
      <postfixExpression tokenValue="'http://google.com'" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="8">
        <leftHandSideExpression tokenValue="'http://google.com'" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="8">
          <newExpression tokenValue="'http://google.com'" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="8">
            <memberExpression tokenValue="'http://google.com'" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="8">
              <primaryExpression tokenValue="'http://google.com'" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="8">
                <literal tokenValue="'http://google.com'" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="8">
                  <stringLiteral tokenValue="'http://google.com'" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="8">
                    <LITERAL tokenValue="'http://google.com'" tokenLine="1" tokenColumn="8"/>
                  </stringLiteral>
                </literal>
              </primaryExpression>
            </memberExpression>
          </newExpression>
        </leftHandSideExpression>
      </postfixExpression>
    </unaryExpression>
```

I need to find the URL. I do it so.

```
//LITERAL[contains(@tokenValue, 'http://')]
```

How to use a regular expression to find url?

```
(http://|https://|ftp://)([a-z0-9]{1})((\.[a-z0-9-])|([a-z0-9-]))*\.([a-z]{2,4})(\/?)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your XPath engine supports XPath 2.0, use `fn:matches` which equivalents `fn:contains` for regular expressions. With XPath 1.0, there is no support for regular expressions.

```
//LITERAL[fn:matches(@tokenValue, '(http://|https://|ftp://)([a-z0-9]{1})((\.[a-z0-9-])|([a-z0-9-]))*\.([a-z]{2,4})(/?)')]
```

Will return all `<LITERAL/>`-tags having an `@tokenValue`-tag matching your regular expression.

There is some problem in your expression, you don't have to (and may not) escape the `/` in the last match group. I fixed that in my query. Why are you using the last two match groups anyway?

Comment: Regular expression found ready. Unfortunately the patch 2.0 is not supported, then will have to look for the links so
`//LITERAL[contains(@tokenValue, 'http://a')]`    
`//LITERAL[contains(@tokenValue, 'http://b')]`    
`//LITERAL[contains(@tokenValue, 'http://c')]`    
etc.     
Tnank You